# cleos get actions for account does not include actions where account is a recipient

Tags: cleos

I was under the impression that following will return all actions on the named account in the range of 0 to 1000.

$ cleos -u  get actions  0 1000

However, it appears that it does not include actions where the named account is a recipient. For example, I have an account where the account has a lot of refund action from eos.names as other EOS accounts outbid me. Now these actions do not show up when I try to get them via get actions.

How can I get ALL actions on a given account where to/from is the account I want to query about.